# Set operator and external column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table named `NewTable` and `OldTable`. Each table contains the same columns which are `id`, `type` and `name` columns. I use set operator (for example: `intersect`) over id and type columns. This work clearly. So I want to add `name` column to select result set but one condition. When procesing the operator don't use `name` column and this must give it in result set.

For example:

```
SELECT id, type FROM NewTable
INTERSECT
SELECT id, type FROM OldTable
```

This query should execution and give me `intersect` row, addition name column in `NewTable`.

Note: I can do it with join operator after `intersect`. But i want to get it directly not to use `join` or others.

Can i do it?

Comment: Short answer - no. That is not how INTERSECT works.

Comment: maybe. but i thought that somebody can.

Comment: No, and this is probably a good thing.  For this to work there would need to be a set-based operator that had a special option to include extra columns from one table in the results but not in the comparison.  The syntax for that would be horrible, and it's such an edge case anyway that it wouldn't be justifiable.

Answer (score 1):

For intersect you can use an inner join, not after the intersect but instead of.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       n.id,
       n.type,
       n.name
       FROM newtable n
            INNER JOIN oldtable o
                       ON o.id = n.id
                          AND o.type = n.type;
```

For except you can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       n.id,
       n.type,
       n.name
       FROM newtable n
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM oldtable o
                                     WHERE o.id = n.id
                                           AND o.type = n.type);
```

I'm not sure what you're seeking for a union, maybe this works for you:

```
SELECT n.id,
       n.type,
       n.name
       FROM newtable n
UNION 
SELECT o.id,
       o.type,
       NULL name
       FROM oldtable o
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM newtable n
                                     WHERE n.id = o.id
                                           AND n.type = o.type);
```

It gets all of the records from `newtable` and the `id` `type` combinations from the `oldtable`, that are not in the new table with a name of `NULL`, as there obviously is no name for it in `newtable`.

Comment: Great. but i can only use this way when i use intersect operator. but except or union

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it with `INTERSECT`, but you can do this with `JOIN`, as already mentioned, or with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM NewTable nt
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OldTable
             WHERE id = nt.id
             AND type = nt.type)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you could achieve this with `INTERSECT`, but not in any way that actually makes sense, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, [type], [name] FROM NewTable
INTERSECT
SELECT o.id, o.[type], n.[name] FROM OldTable o INNER JOIN NewTable n ON n.id = o.id AND n.[type] = o.[type];
```